# React Rainbow UI example missing theme

Tags: reactjs, react-rainbow-components

I'm trying to test the sidebar example from rainbow ui (https://react-rainbow.io/#/Sidebar)

```
    const SideBarContainer = styled.div.attrs(props => {
        return props.theme.rainbow.palette;
    })
```

But I'm getting the error that props.theme.rainbow.palette is unresolved. How can I fix this?

Comment: see this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-wave-rqzr7?file=/src/App.js) I think you need to wrap your "parent" component in a `Application` tag to be able to get theme and rainbow context . Like it's explain in the [doc](https://react-rainbow.io/#/Application)

Comment: I ran into the same error, and I had an "<Application>" element wrapped around the themed objects. The problem was that I had "styled-components" as a dependency in package.json. After removing this dependency it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I explain on my comment you need to wrap your react app in a `Application`component  like explain in the Like it's explain in the [doc](https://react-rainbow.io/#/Application) from React Rainbow :

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Application>
        <Header />
      </Application>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I made a code SandBox of the React Rainbow sideBar demo that I pass in functional components:
[image: Edit ecstatic-http-r67fv]